# Can I have a vector that shares storage with another vector?

Tags: c++, stdvector

In the structure of my application it makes sense for one object to have a vector that is a subset of another vector. And I really mean that the storage of the smaller is contained in the storage of the larger.

Is this possible in C++? I promise that neither vector will ever be resized, and I can probably make it so that the subvector gets destructed before the containing one.

At first I thought that creating a subvector from iterators into the big vector would do the trick, but that makes a copy. I really want a redirect of the bare pointer.

Comment: Is your subset contiguous, meaning `v[i]` to `v[j]` and all the elements in between; or evenly strided, for example every third element of the original vector; or something more general?

Comment: Contiguous. Really, this is the most innocuous and safe case. I'll investigate `gsl::span` which is new to me.

Answer (score 5):

In a word, no. `std::vector` just doesn't do that. But there are two similar things you can do:

1. A vector of pointers (perhaps `std::shared_ptr`), such that one
   vector points at elements from the other. Of course, now you have a vector of pointers to the object, not the object, which may be a problem. One possible idea is `std::reference_wrapper`, but it's not great.
2. There's also `std::span`, which is made for this use case.

Comment: Thanks. Span is new to me. I'll look into it.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout It's a new name for an older idea. Enjoy.

Comment: In a word: Yes, with the appropriate allocator.